# Sample program for Getting JAVA LIST from SPRING MVC 3 CONTROLLER to JQUERY THROUGH AJAX CALL

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

JQUERY:

```
$.ajax({
        datatype:"json",
        url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/appendStudentView.page",
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert("status=="+data)
        },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        alert("xhr=="+xhr+"Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
        }
    });
```

SPRING CONTROLLER

```
/**
 * Handles request for adding two numbers
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/appendStudentView.page")
public @ResponseBody String appendStudentField() {

    List xx=new ArrayList();
    xx.add("CONTROLLER");
return xx;
}
```

I am calling the appendStudentField() method through JQUERY AJAX and returning a list .I am not getting the List xx in the response of the AJAX Call.

Kindly help it .

Thx
Randy

Comment: Are you getting any ERRORS from either the SERVER or in the JavaScript CONSOLE?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) on your classpath? Spring needs Jackson to output JSON.

> This tag registers the
> DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and
> AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter beans
> that are required for Spring MVC to
> dispatch requests to @Controllers. The
> tag configures those two beans with
> sensible defaults based on what is
> present in your classpath. The
> defaults are:
> ...
>
> - Support for reading and writing JSON,
>   if Jackson is present on the
>   classpath.

**Source:**
[Configuring Spring MVC > 15.12.1. mvc:annotation-driven](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a Model and pass your variables that way?  Here is an example bit of code I use.

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
@RequestMapping("/favorites")
public class FavoritesController {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    FavoriteService favoriteService;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void handle(String circuit, String customer, String action, Model model) {

        String userid = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        List<Map<String, String>> favorites = null;

        if (action.equals("save")) {
            favoriteService.setFavorite(userid, circuit, customer);
            favorites = favoriteService.getFavorites(userid);
        }

        if (action.equals("delete")) {
            favoriteService.deleteFavorite(userid, circuit);
            favorites = favoriteService.getFavorites(userid);
        }

        model.addAttribute("userid", userid);
        model.addAttribute("circuit", circuit);
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
        model.addAttribute("favorites", favorites);
    }
}
```

[Edited to add the jquery portion of this]

```
   // **************************************** 
//  SAVE TO FAVORITES 
// ****************************************
$("#save-to-favorite").live("click", function() {
    var saveCircuit = $(this).attr('circuit');
    var saveCustomer = $(this).attr('customer');

    var data = "action=save&circuit=" + saveCircuit + "&customer=" + saveCustomer;
    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        url : "favorites.html",
        data : data,
        success : function(xhr) {
            $("#favorite-list").html(xhr);
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            var response = xhr.responseText;
            response = response.replace(/<html>.+<body>/i, "")
            response = response.replace(/<\/body><\/html>/i, "")

            alert(response);
        }
    });
});

// ****************************************
// DELETE FROM FAVORITES
// ****************************************
$(".delete-favorite-icon").live("click", function() {
    var deleteCircuit = $(this).attr('circuit');

    var data = "action=delete&circuit=" + deleteCircuit;
    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        url : "favorites.html",
        data : data,
        success : function(xhr) {
            $("#favorite-list").html(xhr);
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            var response = xhr.responseText;
            response = response.replace(/<html>.+<body>/i, "")
            response = response.replace(/<\/body><\/html>/i, "")

            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

`